# Multi-container app with custom images from Docker Hub

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

I have a multicontainer docker-compose app (WordPress + MySQL) which I need to share with a developer in a datacentre. The app will be run from there (it'll be a public site), but I won't have direct access to the deployment. So I am going to push the images to Docker Hub, and supply the developer in question with a docker-compose.yml file. The site is static, no uploads, user posts or comments will be added once it's up and running. What I'm not sure about is how many images I need to push - obviously the custom WordPress image, with all my added content, but should I also push the MySQL image? This will have all the data baked in - text from each page, links, etc. I will be running the app behind nginx-proxy, so would also add this to the compose file.

This is the docker-compose file for building the original images:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: some_root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: some_db
      MYSQL_USER: some_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: some_password

  wordpress-app:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "80"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=example.org,example.com,example.local
    volumes:
      - ./wp:/var/www/html

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: mynetwork
```

So I was thinking the docker-compose file I need to supply should look something like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: myrepo/mydb
    restart: always

  wordpress-app:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: myrepo/app
    restart: always

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  whoami:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami.local

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: mynetwork
```

I guess I also need to supply information on ports and hosts there too? And maybe volumes?

In my mind I had the idea that I'd just be pushing a single image, but I guess, given the configuration, I do need the two custom images - WordPress and the MySQL db.

Thanks for any clarification on tihs.

Comment: what do you call custom image ? I don't see any Dockerfile

Comment: You can achieve it in a single image also, using multiple layers. But that would be anti-pattern. Making separate containers for separate services is to be followed. Now coming to your second question, yes, you'll need to expose ports for this container.

Comment: @Nico Good question re the Dockerfile. I have been following the many,many tutorials on migrating a WordPress site to Docker, but none use a Dockerfile. So guess no image is being built... but I'm not clear exactly what wouldgo in the Dockerfile in this scenario. I rely on the volumes forallmy data and content, but how would I BUILD the custom images for the two services?

Comment: You'll have to commit to save changes, for making multiple layers, use Dockerfile.

Comment: @Shirish Ah yes, I forgot about docker commit, thanks.